# How to receive local notification when the app is closed

Tags: c#, xamarin

When the app is open I check to receive local notifications and everything works fine, even in the background.
Only I would like it to do the check even with the app closed, I tried changing the user-permissions and implementing the boot receiver, but I didn't get the results I wanted.
The language is C #

Comment: What platform did you test? each platform require different approach

Comment: I am using visual studio

Comment: Check the link for receiving local notification even if app is closed :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de63b7a6-c2b0-4b9d-a5a7-67b675d29aa2/how-to-show-local-notifications-when-the-app-is-closed-terminated?forum=xamarinandroid, there is a working sample inside it .

Comment: Have you tried the sample in the link ?

Comment: yes, i tried but i still got nothing

Comment: Take a foreground service :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services , it still works even the app is closed .

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager to schedule message for local notification for each platforms

Comment: Does it work even if it has to do a cycle to be repeated periodically, and with the app completely closed?